# Decrypting AES 128 bit Video Stream from Iphone captured on Wireshark

Tags: iphone, aes, encryption

I am trying to decrypt the AES 128 bit Video stream from Iphone4 captured on Wireshark. I have found the bin files with the keys in the m3u8 files on the wireshark traffic but i am not able to find how to decrypt that video data using these keys.

Do anyone knows about any library in c# which can help me in decoding this AES-128 bit encryption of data.

if there is some way to directly decrypt them using that Keys it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Live Streaming specification submitted by Apple specifies quite precisely how the files are encrypted.  Using this information, you should be able to quite easily decrypt each file, then it's just a matter of reading the MPEG2 Transport Stream to decode the media.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-06#section-6.3.6

Potentially this information could be used to bypass DMCA protected content.  It's your responsibility not to do so, or open yourself up to potential liability by doing so.  IANAL, so seek legal advice if this content does not belong to you.

Comment: yeah, i have gone thru the specs and knw how they are encrypted and also captured the required bin files and keys buy i dint got any particular library which will tke this encrypted content and the keys and in return give me decrypted media which i can further decode and play it on some player.

Comment: Then may I recommend finding someone a bit more technical than you to do this. Encryption isn't rocket science, but it does require some basic knowledge.  The program I would use is called OpenSSL, or, I would write a java program to do this after reconstituting the containers from the packet capture. If you're not technical enough to know how to do this, then you really have no need to do it, and should stop what you're doing right now.

Comment: i knw Encryption is nt rocket science and i do have used some Cryptogrpahic libs in Java for it like bouncyCastle for Java but i dint got enough reference for C# things. without encryption i do have written entire code for writing the decoding code and then further playing it over my own player also. I just need to some C# library to do the decryption stuff due to time constraint for me.  Thanks for you time.